# Java: calling an Objectmethod with a variable

Tags: java, object, methods

I would like to call up an Method for a library like:

```
%nameofbookvar%.islend();
```

but the user should assign the nameofbookvar to the book he wants. So I want java to know that nameofbookvar is a variable and not the name of the object.
How can I do this?

Thanks!!:)

Comment: What is a book? I can't understand your question really. You want the user to specify the name of a variable? Why?

Comment: I would like to write a programm for a booklibrary and the programm should check if the from the user specified book is lend or not.

Comment: But you're not going to create a new *variable* for every book in your library. How would you add a new book without changing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the books in the library in a Map where the key is the name of the book the user wants and the mapped value is the Book object that belongs to the book in question. For different types of Maps refer to the Implementing Classes in the [Map specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and determine which works best for your needs.

```
public class Library {
    private HashMap<String, Book> collection;

    public Library() {
        collection = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Book getBook(String name) {
        return collection.get(name);
    }

    public void addBook(String name, Book book) {
        collection.put(name, book);
    }
}

public class Book {
    private boolean isLend;

    public boolean isLend() {
        return isLend;
    }
}
```

You can then call the following on a Library object

```
Library library = new Library(); // Don't forget to add books
library.getBook(%nameofbookvar%).isLend();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's something really weird to do on Java because you normally won't create variables like `%nameofbookvar%` without... defining its name, correct?

For a simple name/value pair, you can use a `HashMap`:

```java
Map<String, Book> library = new HashMap<String, Book>();
library.put("Frankenstein", new Book("Frankenstein"));
// ....
Book userSearchedBook = library.get("Frankenstein");
userSearchedBook.isLend();
```

Of course, you'll need a `Book` class:

```java
public class Book {
    private final String title;
    private boolean lend;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    //...
    public boolean isLend() {
        return isLend;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to create objects of the books that the "realworld" library has and then let the User specify which book he wants so in the code I would write:

Comment: Sry, pressed wrong key. :)                                                                       I want to create objects of the books that the "realworld" library has and then let the User specify which book he wants so in the code I would let the User define the variable with a user input. So the name of the varable shouldn´t change but the content, and I want Java to use the content of a variable as the name of an Object

Answer (score 0):

```
Book variable = BookStore.get(theBookTheUserWants);
variable.isLend();
```